# Groovy - filter out from array dates that are less than x days apart

Tags: date, groovy

I have this array of dates

```
[2020-06-17,
2020-06-21,
2020-06-22,
2020-06-26,
2020-08-03,
2020-08-05,
2020-08-13,
2020-09-16,
2020-11-18,
2021-01-10,
2021-01-15]
```

I want to get a new array with only those dates that are within 7 days of at least one other date.

```
[2020-06-17,
2020-06-21,
2020-06-22,
2020-06-26,
2020-08-03,
2020-08-05,
2021-01-10,
2021-01-15]
```

As you can see in the example, 2020-06-26 is more than 7 days apart from 2020-06-17 but is less than 7 days apart from 2020-06-21 and 2020-06-22.

Any idea on how to do that will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: task condition is not complete. for example the following array has 2 groups of dates with less then 7 days apart : `[ 2020-1-1, 2020-1-2, 2020-2-1, 2020-2-2 ]` - do you want to keep at least one group as a result? which one?

Comment: In your example I would like to keep all of them since the second date is one day after the first date and the fourth date is one day after the third date.

Comment: is it correct to say: you want to keep all the dates that has at least one 7-days-apart pair?

Comment: The title is misleading and I will correct it. I want to keep all the dates that are less than 7 days apart.

Comment: @HananCohen I've rephrased your request in the question body to "I want to get a new array with only those dates that are less than 7 days apart from at least one other date.".  I believe this is accurate, correct?  Your previous statement was very ambiguous (7 days apart from what, exactly).

Comment: @HananCohen What do you want to happen when two days are exactly 7 days apart (e.g. 2022-06-01 and 2022-06-08)?

Comment: @M.Justin You rephrased my question correctly. less or equal to 7 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple yet inefficient (quadratic [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)) solution would be to iterate through the list, and filter to keep all elements that have another date in the list within seven days of it.  Given array `LocalDate[]` named `dates`, and assuming no duplicates in the array (or that duplicates should not be considered for the determination):

```groovy
LocalDate[] result = dates.findAll { d1 ->
    dates.find { d2 -> d1 != d2 && (d1 - d2).abs() <= 7 }
}
```

Note that the [`groovy-datetime`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-datetime) library is needed to subrtract the days in this manner (`d1 - d2`).  This is automatically provided by [`groovy-all`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-all), but not by [`groovy`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy).

### Explanation

The [`findAll`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object%5B%5D.html#findAll(groovy.lang.Closure)) method on `Object[]` is used to return dates matching the given closure condition.

```groovy
dates.findAll { d1 -> ... }
```

The closure uses the [`find`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure)) method on `Collection` to return the first element matching the given condition, or `null` if no match:

```groovy
dates.find { d2 -> ... }
```

Since `null` is falsey and all `LocalDate` values are truthy, the outer `findAll` call only includes values where this inner `find` returns a value.

Finally, the closure used by `find` checks that the two dates are different (thereby skipping the case where the same index is checked, as well as skipping any duplicate dates).  It also confirms that the number of days between the two is 7 or less.

```
{ d2 -> d1 != d2 && (d1 - d2).abs() <= 7 }
```

Subtracting two `LocalDate` values returns the number of days between those dates, per the [`minus`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/LocalDate.html) method added to that class by Groovy.  Taking the absolute value of that difference per [`Number.abs`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#abs()) normalizes the result to a positive number, regardless of whether the smaller or larger date was first.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75523506/1108305), a quadratic-time solution is very straightforward.  The following solution has better time complexity — O(n log n) — at the expense of being a less simple solution and copying/sorting the input data.

```groovy
List<LocalDate> sortedDates = dates.sort(false)
LocalDate[] result = sortedDates.withIndex().findResults { d ->
    def (LocalDate date, int index) = d
    LocalDate previous = index == 0 ? null : sortedDates[index - 1]
    LocalDate next = index == sortedDates.size() - 1
            ? null : sortedDates[index + 1]

    return (previous && date - previous <= 7)
            || (next && next - date <= 7) ? date : null
}
```

This solution works by sorting the data, and for each record checking whether either of its neighbors are within seven days of it.  If they are, it's included in the resulting array.  If not, it's excluded.